# Как преобразовать из System::String^ в int?

Tags: c++-cli

Добрый вечер, взялся за изучение C++ на Visual C++ 2010 Express. Как преобразовать из `System::String^` в `int`? Нерабочий пример:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    int i;
    i = Convert::ToInt32(button1->Text);
    MessageBox::Show(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
  try {
     int x = Int32::Parse(buttonX->Text);
  }
  catch (FormatException^) {
  }
```